# I2C & SPI Operating at the same time

Tags: microcontroller, i2c, spi, atmega328p

I'm starting to learn AVR microcontrollers. I used some books,  and the hardware I use is the ATMega328P. I would just like to ask if both SPI and I2C can operate at the same time. Thanks for the awesome replies!

Comment: Both interfaces are designed to send and receive data. Do you mean can these interfaces be configured as a master or as a slave?

Comment: I'm sorry haha.. I mean can I use those both peripherals at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

I2C and SPI not only have different PIN locations, but also they do not share any hardware or interrupts.

Therefore, like many other ATMega IC's, you can use both I2C and SPI. I have done this in many projects.
[image]